# Google App Engine Request Status

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

Is it possible to set the http request status to 200 even if the system throws 500?
I have a task which is running. When GAE throws http request 500 i want to manually set it to 200 at end of task so as to prevent the task from being retried.

Comment: Can you not just turn off retries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical pattern to return a *200 status code* is to wrap your code between `try` and `except` clauses:

```
try:
  do your stuff      
except:
  logging.error("Something bad happened")
```

This example catch all the exceptions returning always a `200 status code` , in your application you might want to add a proper list of exceptions to catch; for certain types of *transient* exceptions it is correct to raise a 500 error that implicitly say to App Engine to try the task again.

**EDIT:**
As correctly suggested, you should use `logging.exception` instead of `logging.error` to include the stacktrace in the log.

```
try:
  do your stuff      
except:
  logging.exception("Something bad happened") #It will log the stacktrace too
```

This has a second benefit, it allows you to receive log reports via email after enabling the [ereporter](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter.html) service.

Comment: Use logging.exception instead of logging.error, so it will include the stacktrace.

Comment: If you have a minute, I'd love a code example of using logging.exception to include the stacktrace in the log.